# Will boost converter spike kill LED?

Tags: led, boost, led-driver

So I am attempting to design an LED driver that takes 7.2V and converts it to 36V at 2.4A. For this task I am utilising a boost converter but the problem I am seeing is that the model shows a initial spike of 150V before stabilising to 36V.
[image]

My main questions are: is there any way to reduce/remove this? Will it even be an issue? And is a boost converter the best circuit to drive an LED such as this?

The datasheet for the LED: https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/723/XLamp_CXB3590_Pro9-3079479.pdf

The model I am  using is "CXB3590-0000-00PN0U0A30G" and since the datasheet contains every LED in that series you will have to ctrl+F and paste it in to find the correct one. However, that only shows lumen values and the like, the graphs are further down.

Comment: These resistor values aren't very realistic; have you checked the pin ratings on the 555? | 555 isn't a good choice for SMPS use as it has no built-in control features. It can be (ab)used that way, but there are MUCH better choices. Would you perhaps be better served by asking a question in one of these directions instead?

Comment: You're building a constant voltage boost converter, but to drive that LED you should use a constant current boost converter.  Otherwise you're going to be burning a lot of heat on a current limiting resistor at 2+ amps.  Rather than CV using a 555, get an LED boost driver IC.  Probably cost you less than a dollar.

Comment: Hmm yeah maybe using an IC will be a better option, I'll try and find one.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer your question "is this even an issue?".

Yes.

If that simulation is to be believed, you have an average of 100V across 15Ω, for about 20ms.

That's an average current through the load of:

$$ I=\frac{V}{R}=\frac{100V}{15\Omega} \approx 6A $$

With a string of LEDs as the load instead, you can count on the LEDs to clamp the voltage to 40V (until they fail), but not the current, which will likely exceed this estimate.

With a sustained over-current of this magnitude, those LEDs likely won't last 20ms.

With the 555 in this role, and with no feedback to modulate the 555 output's pulse width, there is no regulation. The fact that this circuit settles at about 40V is coincidence. You've chosen a load value of 15Ω, which together with a lot of other unknowns in this circuit, just happens to produce 40V out in the long term, under these simulated conditions.

Your LEDs aren't a 15Ω load, and with LEDs in place instead of (or even with) that resistance, results will be very different, and probably catastrophic.

As it stands, I think this design will damage the LEDs in short order. You probably *can* use a 555 in this role, if you somehow employed feedback and the "CONTROL" input of the 555 timer, or equivalent, but such a redesign is probably beyond the scope of a simple answer here.

---

If you are going to the trouble of building a boost converter, then instead of aiming to obtain a fixed voltage output, aim for a fixed current instead.

When trying to use a fixed voltage, you require a resistance in series with the LED string in order to control current flow, and that resistance will waste energy, and get hot.

A DC-DC converter IC designed for constant current output alleviates the need for a large series resistor, but is otherwise quite similar to a boost converter configured to output a fix voltage. It seems silly to build a constant voltage DC-DC converter to power LEDs, when the same or similar components in a constant current configuration would do a much better job at controlling LED current.

Comment: I have discovered this: https://www.ti.com/product/TPS92691-Q1 which seems to be what I want. It is a bit outside of my expertise thought and I will need to thoroughly investigate it beforehand.

Comment: @leasthollow That looks like a very capable IC. I'd look for something simpler, but you're going in the right direction.

Comment: The problem is that I don't fully know what I need other than 7.2V input, 36V output at 2.4A, finding something that can do that is apparently challenging, or more accurately, I don't know how the voltage and current controls on these ICs work :'(

Answer (score 0):

555 isn't really intended for SMPSU design.

555's start with a long pulse (which is possibly the problem). but in your circuit this can be eliminated by splitting C1 into two halves connecting one THRS to GND and the other THRS to VCC.

```
 GND --||-- THRS --||-- VCC
```

Also the resistors are kind of small. increase them by 10x and reduce  c1 (and its twin) by the same factor.